# Are there side-effects by switching the primary and secondary categories of an App in iTunesConnect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app on the App Store with a Primary and Secondary category set. The app is featured in some of these categories, and this is something I would very much like to keep.

Are there any side-effects to the app's featured status, app rankings or anything else simply by switching which category is primary, and which is secondary (but otherwise, keeping the same 2 categories)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only speak from my experience (!) with more than 12 apps on the iOS App Store for more than 2 years. Most of our apps are in the Productivity (1st) and Business Category (2nd).

We did some tests on ranking and changed the categories (2nd=>1st etc.). The changes (mainly number of downloads) were significant - positive and negative. Obviously there are also different price points that people are willing to pay in different categories.

With regards to featured status we observed that you often get kicked out of the former first category's featured section (New and Noteworthy etc.).

What I can tell you is that sometimes it is worth testing some changes: For us it was worth testing the different categories and when we changed all the stuff back to the "original" setup, the numbers of downloads etc. were the same.